# Netbeans Connector And Chrome - MAC OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, netbeans

I recently migrated my development IDE NetBeans, from Linux to MAC OSX.

The problem is that I can not debug my Java EE project in Chrome using the NetBeans Connector extension.

Simply by requesting debugging, Chrome opens only one blank page with the URL `file:///private/var/folders/xc/2h230k1j75q4s7hk1mymy40r0000gp/T/blank6473583437075718674.html` and nothing else happens.

If I access through the localhost address: `localhost:8080/ProjectName`, the application works normally, however I can not debug this condition.

In NetBeans LOG there is no error, and in Chrome when opening the Developer Tool, it appears in the console only `<html: netbeans_temporary = "true"> </ html>`

The NetBeans version is 8.2, the Chrome version is 63.0.3239.84 (Official version) 64-bit, and the NetBeans Connector version is 1.1.5.