# Chrome Netbeans Plugin only shows blank page

Tags: angularjs, netbeans, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning AngularJS at the moment and thought I would install netbeans as it supports debugging in chrome via a plugin. Or claims to at least...

I have followed the user guides and tutorials that I've found and always seem to falter at the same point:

1. Install Netbeans
2. Install chrome plugin
3. Create a simple sample project
4. Set the default web browser to Chrome with Plugin
5. Click run

At this point I always see a blank page loaded in Chrome. I suspect that this is a bug as all of the resources online seem sure that I should be able to see the default index.hmtl page in my browser...

I'm running on a MAC:

[image: MAC Info]

And my plugin version is:

[image: Plugin Info]

My Netbeans version:

[image: Netbeans Info]

My Default Browser in Netbeans:

[image]

Does anyone know of any issues with running this configuration? No matter what I do I just see a blank page with a mangled URL like so when I hit run:

```
http://file:///private/var/folders/4l/3gq9477n6_952q1ztvz5ngdckcdyx4/T/blank2587611836421039861.html
```

When I open this file in VI I see one line in it:

```
<html :netbeans_temporary="true"></html>
```

Comment: Someone also updated a NetBeans bug report on this issue today - was that you? See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245227 . If that wasn't you, could you please add any relevant error in the NetBeans log to your post. That file will be named ../var/log/messages.log under the directory where NetBeans was installed.

Comment: FYI another SO poster has the same problem; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848693/netbeans-connector-and-chrome-mac-osx?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work as a workaround for me:

1. Open the project configuration and change the browser from Chrome with netbeans connector to Chrome
2. Run the project (the correct page should come up in Chrome)
3. Click on the Netbeans Connector in the upper right corner of the Chrome window
4. Select "Debug in Netbeans" (You should get the yellow information notice across the top of the window)
5. Go back to Netbeans and click on the 'debug main project' button.

My configuration is os/x High Sierra, Netbeans 8.2